# Catching arrival of new smartcard reader in Citrix terminal session

Tags: c++, citrix, smartcard-reader, winscard

According to MSDN there is special virtual reader \?PNP?\Notification that allows get notification of arrival of new smartcard reader (via [SCardGetStatusChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function).
My code look like (error handling and checks are omitted):

```
while (true)
{
    SCardGetStatusChange(hContext, INFINITE, rgReaderStates, cReaders);
    // rgReaderStates[0] - \\?PNP?\Notification
    WorkWithNewReader();
}
```

This code works perfect on non-terminal session.
But via Citrix terminal session function SCardGetStatusChange immediately returns and rgReaderStates[0].dwEventState is 7 (SCARD_STATE_UNKNOWN).
So, how i could recieve notification of inserting new smartcard reader?

Comment: I cannot answer, but using smart cards for virtual or remote devices is something that has been proven *very unreliable* at my workplace.